# generate random stack memory address

Tags: python-3.x

How can I generate random memory addresses

between **`0x7fffffffffff`** and **`0x7fffffff0000`**

and then pack it with **`struct.pack("L", var)`**

**so in the end it will print something like:**

```
$ python3 -c 'import struct; print(struct.pack("L", 0x7fffffffd292))'
b'\x92\xd2\xff\xff\xff\x7f\x00\x00'
```

Addresses should not contain null byte `(\x00)`, except the suffix which struct adds

Comment: Why do you think an address won't ever contain a null byte? Without that restriction you can just pick a number at random from your range. Even if you keep the restriction, it may be easiest to just pick randomly and repick if you happen to get a null by chance (should be about 1 in 128, if I'm doing my probabilities right).

Comment: `0x7fffffffffff` and `0x7fffffff0000` are just `int`s.  Use [`random.randint(0x7fffffff0000, 0x7fffffffffff)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint)

Comment: @PatrickHaugh randint >32 will print ASCII char without \x prefix

Comment: @Blckknght not sure I understand your question, why ? because I use it to inside BOF exploit which cannot have null byte.. FFFF = 65535

Comment: Oh. I see.  You need to feed the 'attack input' to an interface that takes a string, so internal null characters would terminate the string early, truncating the 'attack payload'.

Comment: Just pick randomly using `randint`, and test each byte for null using AND-masks.  E.g., `cand = random.randint(0x7fffffff0000, 0x7fffffffffff)` then retry `if (cand & 0xff00000000000000) == 0` or `if (cand & 0x00ff0000000000000) == 0` or ... You'd have an 8/256 chance of retrying.

Comment: You could even use the length of the string after packing to see if you need to retry.  That would be much cleverer.

Comment: @lockcmpxchg8b exactly, please post an answer with code so I will approve & others will enjoy it in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate your addresses in a loop, recreating it if the previous one had a null byte. Addresses are just integers, so you can use `random.randint` to create them:

```
import random

n = 0 # inital value, obviously has null bytes
while n & 0xff == 0 or n & 0xff00 == 0:
    n = random.randint(0x7fffffff0000, 0x7fffffffffff)

# use n here, e.g. struct.pack or whatever
```

Most of the time you'll only need one pass through the loop. Only if you get especially unlucky will you need several tries.

Comment: thank you, but, using struct.pack("L", n) the output is not as requested, sometimes without "\x", have you tested your answer ?

Comment: You won't get an `\x` prefix on any byte that corresponds to an ASCII character, you'll just get the character itself. That's just how bytestrings are handled by `repr`, it has nothing to do with the content not being what you want. For instance `b'\x68\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f\x20\x77\x6f\x72\x6c\x64'` is the same bytestring as `b'hello world'` (and the latter will be what `repr` will show).

Comment: thanks for the explaining, it was part of the request, i prefer to do it python and not in C, how can I adjust the repr ? and by your answer just to clarify, it will send the same bytes via socket it's just output string representation by the repr

Comment: If you're using a socket in Python, just use `sock.write(your_bytes)` and don't worry about the `repr` at all. The `repr` isn't what gets written to the socket, that will be the raw byte values.

Comment: but I do want to reproduce it which means I need to original address, can I adjust the repr ?

Comment: At this point I have no idea what you really want. I thought you wanted a number, or bytes, but you seem to actually want a non-standard `repr` of a byte string for who knows what reason. Seriously, you should just try doing whatever you're going to do with the bytes instance directly (or with its `repr` even if it contains non-escaped bytes). It will probably just work, and your concerns and extra questions are completely unnecessary.

Comment: I need to feed 'attack input' to an interface that takes a string which represent memory address